# Way over the limit of shared database on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I noticed today that my database is way over the 5MB limit on the shared database I'm using for a RoR app.

```
Addons:        New Relic Standard, PG Backups Basic, Shared Database 5MB
Database Size: 135M
```

Have they turned off the limits now when they release the new plans (dev, basic, crane)?

Anyone else experiencing this? Haven't gotten any notifications, warnings or anything... Still works like a charm though, it seems.

Comment: Have you possibly been charged and didn't notice?

Comment: Not that I can see. And no invoices either :) But I'll have to upgrade to Basic now anyways, so it doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB limits traditionally have always been soft limits on the shared databases - but on the new plans you receive an email when you exceed the allocated row count (I've already received one!).

I would guess that the old shared databases will be retired soon and you'll have to move up to one of the new plans.

Comment: Yes, so it seems. They obviously just didn't care about my big database. Tonight I got some emails that I have to migrate my apps to dev/basic anyways. Seems easy enough :)